# Console calculator continued calculations

Tags: c#

How do i add continued calculation to my C# Calculator?

As an example I have 2 numbers they sum to 5, and I want to be able to add 5 to the result from earlier.How do i accomplish this?

```
public class regneoperato : tilfældig
{
    public static void hej()
    {     
        int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string regneoperator = Console.ReadLine();
        int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int result = 0;

        switch (regneoperator)
        {
            case "+":
                result = number1 + number2;
                break;

            case "-":
                result = number1 - number2;
                break;

            case "/":
                if (number2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Jeg kan ikke dividere med 0");
                }
                result = number1 / number2;
                break;

            case "*":
                result = number1 * number2;
                break;                    
       }            
       Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Do you about "loops" yet in your learning?

Comment: Have you learned about `while` yet? Also, please don't put tags in your title.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes i know loops thanks and i have tried to put this into a while loop but then it just repeat it obviously but it need to save the result so i can do further calculations on it

Comment: @BradleyDotNET i am sorry please see my comment :)

Comment: It *is* saved... it's the number in "result"

Comment: @Anoxy You can store your result in a variable; just as you already do. Obviously that would need to be at a class level.

Comment: @eddie_cat i know it is in result but i dont know how i will be able to do further calculations on result

Answer (score 3):

just set one of your arguements to the result

```
var number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

do
{
    //everything else

    number1 = result;
}while(/*insert condition here*/);
```